# navigator.online always returning true in all browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, navigator, internet-connection

I am unable to figure out why in my machine when I try to test navigator.online

I am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I even tried the mdn service [View  a live example.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have searched for answers but none have the solution to my problem. I just want to listen to events for being online and offline and run my logic accordingly.

EDIT :

I tried the command : `ip route ls` and I am not sure if this is the reason. I am not familiar with routing on linux

[image]

Comment: I am simply running the "navigator.online" command in all my browsers as you can see the results in the screenshots. I disconnect my wifi and run these commands and it returns me true instead of false

Comment: The page you linked to explains that it's not reliable when it returns true. It may only mean that it's able to reach your router among other things.